# C# Entity Framework Group Count

Tags: c#, .net, highcharts

Currently working on getting data into some sort of array for a DotNet.Highcharts chart. I have a problem with getting the data out of my database. Entity framework is giving me the following error:

DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.

```
 select t.code, type, count(type)
 from tbl_data d
 join tbl_code t on d.code_name = t.code_id
 where type is not null
 group by code, type 
 order by code

        using (Context db = new Context())
        {
            var data = db.tbl_data
                .Where(d => d.type != null)
                .GroupBy(d => new { d.tbl_code.code, d.type })
                .Select(d => new { name = d.Key.code, type = d.Key.type , count = d.Key.type.Count() })
                .OrderBy(d => new { d.name, d.type });

            List<string> x_Axis = new List<string>();
            List<object[]> y_Axis = new List<object[]>();

            foreach (var d in data)
            {
                x_Axis.Add(d.name);
                y_Axis.Add(new object[] { d.type, d.count });
            }

            var xArray = x_Axis.ToArray();

            render_Chart(xArray, y_Axis);
        }
```

A sample of the data from SQL is below.

```
code    type (No column name)
eis06   a    49
eis06   b    3
eis07   a    33
eis08   a    38
eis09   a    32
eis09   b    68
eis14   a    17
eis14   b    34
eis15   a    24
eis15   b    17
eis16   a    27
eis16   b    16
```

Edited because the initial problem was trivial, this new problem is blocking me now.